# How to Store Personal Settings in WebPart?

Tags: web-part, settings

I want to allow a user to store personal information in my WebPart.

So I have a property:

```
 [WebBrowsable(true)]
 [WebDisplayName("Tag")]
 [Pages.SPWebCategoryName("Tag to display")]
 [Pages.WebPartStorage(Pages.Storage.Personal)]
 [WebDescription("You would put the description here.")]
 [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.User)]
 public string Tag { get; set; }
```

The customer wants to update the **Tag** property in the SharePoint WebPart directly on "OK" button click!

```
protected void OnButtonClick(...)
{
    var text = tb.Text;
    this.WebPart.Tag = text;
    // How to store?
}
```

How do I save the information for a specific user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in your click event:

- Get the limitedwebpartmanager for the current page, in whichever scope you wish
- ask that webpartmanager for the webpart with the id == this.ID (aka, this webpart)
- edit the property
- webpartmanager.savechanges(webpart);

You'll need to refresh the page but I believe that should work to set the property for the web part.

Comment: Sound like a plan. I will try this one.

Answer (score 0):

This is bad solution because each user should check in page on self after each update.

So its better to store data somewhere else.